# Html table gets distorted only on one page

Tags: html, css, web, html-table

I have a website with a table and for some reason that I cannot find for the love of god, the last item of the table row is wider than previous items. Here is a [link](http://proffupack.ru/catalog/odnorazovye_plastikovye_pishchevye_konteynery/?SECTION_CODE=odnorazovye_plastikovye_pishchevye_konteynery&SHOWALL_1=1) to see what I mean.
  However, it only does that on some pages. Most pages are completely fine. Here is an example of what its supposed to look like [this](http://proffupack.ru/catalog/bumazhnye_podarochnye_pakety/?SECTION_CODE=bumazhnye_podarochnye_pakety&SHOWALL_1=1).

The code is the same on every page and I do not quite understand why it does that because the 'inspect element' gives me that the width of the table element is the same. However, it clearly is not. Please check it out and let me know where to start looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below content in one of the bottom rows is causing the issue -

`СК-201(М),231(М),251(М),351(М),501(М)`

Its in the 5th row from bottom. 
[image]

Add space after comma to solve the issue.

Comment: Or you can add `.catalog_item_name > div > a{word-wrap:break-word;}` style in your css.

Answer (score 1):

some time data come from data store and you cant hanld this with adding space in the table when long words comes in then td width should extend its simple to solve this issue in css add this line for you td css

```
word-break: break-all;
```

your css will be look like

```
.catalog_items_blocks td {
  padding: 10px 0 38px 41px;
  width: 179px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

now words breaks when cross the td width
thanks

Comment: Yeah my boss does not like when the words break.

Comment: but if any words comes with width more then td width then you will face same problem again